# How can I more easily delegate all tasks in a role in Ansible?

Tags: ansible

I'm still somewhat new to Ansible so I'm sure this isn't the proper way of doing this, but it's what I've come up with considering the requirements I was given.

I have to perform tasks on a server, which I do not have credentials to access since they are locked in a vault. My way of working around this is to get the credentials from the vault, then delegate tasks to that server. I've accomplished this, but I'm wondering if there is a cleaner or more adequate way of doing it. So, here's my setup:

I have a playbook that just has:

```
---
- hosts: localhost

  roles:
    - role: get_credentials         <-- Not the real role names
    - role: use_credentials
```

Basically, get_credentials gets some credentials from a vault and then use_credentials performs tasks, but each task has

```
delegate_to: protected_server
  vars:
    ansible_ssh_user: "{{ user }}"
    ansible_ssh_pass: "{{ password }}"
```

at the end of it

Is there a way I can delegate all the tasks in use_credentials without having to delegate each task individually?

Answer (score 0):

I'ld move both your role from the `roles:` section to the `tasks:`, using `include_role`. Something like this:

```yaml
tasks:
  - name: Get credentials
    include_role:
      name: get_credentials        # I expect this one to set_fact user_from_get_credential and password_from_get_credential
    delegate_to: protected_server

  - name: Use credentials
    include_role:
      name: use_credentials
    vars:
      ansible_ssh_user: "{{ user_from_get_credential }}"
      ansible_ssh_pass: "{{ password_from_get_credential }}"
```